# Center Video background and remove horizontal bar

Tags: video

I have a section with full video background. i want to video to center and to be resized when the browser window is resized, but the video doens't center, and there is always an horizontall bar on it.

I've already tried everything.

```
#video-landing video {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -100;
 margin:0 auto;
}
#video-landing{

    min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  color: white;
};
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRrZwb